# PHP OOP : Accessing parent attributes from child / Child inheriting from parent's attributes

Tags: php, oop

so the code is : DAO class

```
    abstract class DAO  
    {   
    protected $db; 
    protected $SQL_host='localhost';
    protected $SQL_port='3306';
    protected $SQL_dbname='projet'; 
    protected $SQL_login='root'; 
    protected $SQL_password='';

    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->setDb(new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->SQL_host.';port='.$this->SQL_port.';dbname='.$this->SQL_dbname, $this->SQL_login, $this->SQL_password)) ;
    }

    protected function setDb(PDO $bdd)
    {
        $this->db = $bdd ;
    }


    }
```

and child UserDAO class

```
     class UserDAO extends DAO 
     {
     public function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct();
     }
     }
```

When UserDAO child class inherits from parent DAO, does the child get parent's attributes ?
If not, how can I make so ?

I've been looking around and they mostly tell to use get function but that's really not what i'm trying to do. Thanks for your help

Comment: Please **read** the  PHP docs... they are a good read....

Comment: Did you try to call a parent property and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the subclass inherits the parent class's members.

Comment: do I have to rewrite them ? something like on the child class : protected $db = parent::db, because on my child class i'll have to use something like $request = $this->db->prepare(insert request here);

Comment: no.  your child class *inherits* `protected $db`.  You can do `$this->db-> ...` in your child class *as if it were declared in the child class itself*, so long as you properly initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as yourself. I wanted child classes to inherit the database pdo instance. The problem was, if I had multiple models ("users" and "documents" for example), it ended up creating multiple pdo instances (super wasteful). I resorted to dependency injection. I created the instance outside the class, then passed it to any class that needed pdo:

```
class UserDAO extends DAO 
{
     public function __construct($db=NULL)
     {
         if($db){//if database is requested
        parent::__construct($db);
    }
     }
}
```

There are loads of arguments for or against dependency injection - but I found this to work the most efficiently for myself.

In answer to your question, it seems you're doing it right (though, like I said, with PDO it might not be the best). Make sure both classes are included in your script.